# Using array_multisort to sort date of type '28-jul-17'?

Tags: php, date

I have data that is in a multi-dimensional array that has a date attached to it of the format '28-Jul-17'.  I would like to sort my data in ascending or descending date order. I am able to sort my multi-dimensional array, but I do not know how to sort the data out.  My question is, which flag should I use to in this function to get the result that I require?  At the moment I am using SORT_DESC or SORT ASC and this does not sort my date out in chronological order.

I am using the following:

```
 array_multisort($fieldOfInterest, SORT_DESC , $arrayOfDictionary);
```

Sorting type flags:

```
SORT_REGULAR - compare items normally (don't change types)
SORT_NUMERIC - compare items numerically
SORT_STRING - compare items as strings
SORT_LOCALE_STRING - compare items as strings, based on the current locale. It uses the locale, which can be changed using setlocale()
SORT_NATURAL
```

Comment: you need to use custom sort function for that

Comment: The default flags don't magically know how to sort some custom date format. You'll have to parse the date correctly yourself into a comparable value. → https://stackoverflow.com/a/17364128/476

Comment: Add your array structure plz

Comment: Step one: Convert all the dates into timestamps or DateTime objects. Step two: Sort as normal. Step three: Convert back to human-readable date format when outputting for display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with default flags of `array_multisort()`, because they don't know about ***custom-date-formats***.

Instead of it you can do something like below:-

```
function compare_dates($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['date']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['date']);
    return ($t1 >$t2) ? 1:-1; //changing 1 and -1 position will make it descending
}    
usort($array, 'compare_dates'); // here $array is multi-dimensional array
```

Output:- https://eval.in/842881  OR  https://eval.in/842882